# Listen cmd.exe by external application

Tags: windows, cmd

ı want to listen cmd.exe with my own application. I want to this. my application is running someone write cmd.exe and press enter button, my application realize that and take this command. Please someone answer me.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. You'll have to hire a developer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
:loop
    Set /p Input=%CD%^>
    rem do what you want, here we execute it
    %input%
Goto loop
```

Mimics a command prompt. See `set /?` and `goto /?`.